# Animate group expansion at every time that I expand the group

Tags: android, android-widget, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to imlpement some animation to be played **every time that I expand a group** of an `ExpandableListView`. So far I do the following the getChildView of my custom adapter (based on `BaseExpandableListAdapter`):

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // Auto-generated method stub
    ExpandListChild child = (ExpandListChild) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = 
                (LayoutInflater) m_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);

        AnimatorSet anim = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(m_context, 
                R.animator.expand_list_animation);

        anim.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        anim.start();
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
    tv.setText(child.getName());
    tv.setTag(child.getTag());

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cb.setChecked(child.getState());
    return view;
}
```

The problem is that because I am applying the animation only when creating a new view, this only works the first time that the group is expanded. I also tried to apply it in any case (not only when `view==null`) but the problem is that the animation is played for all expanded children (even those of other groups that are already expanded).

I have been trying a lot to get this to work and I cannot figure out how. Your help is appreciated.